# Can't resolve dependency on maven2 artifact "jersey-media-multipart"

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, ivy, parent-pom

My ivy.xml can’t resolve dependency on “jersey-media-multipart” library using ibiblio resolver (I believe the root of that resolver is at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/).
I have an ivy.xml file that includes just one dependency like below:

```
<ivysettings>
  <properties file="${ivy.settings.dir}/ivysettings.properties"/>
  <settings defaultResolver="maven-repos"/>
  <resolvers>
    <filesystem name="local">
      <ivy pattern="${ivy.local.default.root}/${ivy.local.default.ivy.pattern}" />
      <artifact pattern="${ivy.local.default.root}/${ivy.local.default.artifact.pattern}"/>
    </filesystem>
    <chain name="maven-repos">
      <ibiblio name="libraries" m2compatible="true"/>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

My resolve statement extract from build.xml looks like this:

```
<target name="resolve" description="retrieve dependencies with ivy"/>
```

When ivy tries to resolve that dependency I get an error during ivy resolve command:

```
[ivy:retrieve]
[ivy:retrieve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]          ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]          :: org.glassfish.jersey.media#jersey-media-multipart;2.28: org.glassfish.jersey.media#project;2.28->org.glassfish.jersey#project;2.28->org.eclipse.ee4j#project;1.0.5
[ivy:retrieve]          ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]
[ivy:retrieve]
[ivy:retrieve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
```

I have checked maven2 central repository and verified that there is a pom.xml in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/ee4j/project/1.0.5/
called project-1.0.5.pom . 
Why am I getting this error then?

Kind Regards,
Janusz

Comment: Please don't post same questions again and again. You have already posted another question on same problem: Possible duplicate of [Ivy dependency on org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56014615/ivy-dependency-on-org-glassfish-jersey-media-jersey-media-multipart-fails)

Comment: Sorry. My previous question was not explained clearly so I created new one with more details. Sorry about that.

Comment: Is it possible to remove my old question?

Comment: Yes you can delete your question. See : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63983/can-i-delete-my-own-question. Also,in future, you can simply edit your existing question rather than deleting and creating a new one.

Comment: I will retract the duplicate flag once you delete the other question

Comment: I have deleted previous one.